How to use WS-Security with Spring Boot and client stubs
I'm trying to understand how to use WS-Security with Spring Boot and client stubs generated from WSDL. My goal is to include WS-Security header with XML Signature to SOAP request with no code changes to generated clients. Inclusion of security header and signature must be configuration driven behaviour.
I know it's possible to use Wss4jSecurityInterceptor with Spring's WebServiceTemplate, but I want to use generated client stubs to call the service. With Spring, how to enable WS-Security in case of generated client stubs? I can use any maven plugin for client generation if that matters.

Why don't you use an interceptor to all request to add another layer check ? You will basically just call the WS soap client to make requests which will be intercepted. IT's also doable with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor .

If you are using generated clients you are using some sort of libary like Apache CXF, read the documentation of the library you are using to create the client stubs.
